# python pandas dataframe columns convert to dict key and value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-conversion

I have a pandas data frame with multiple columns and I would like to construct a dict from two columns: one as the dict's keys and the other as the dict's values. How can I do that?

Dataframe:

```
           area  count
co tp
DE Lake      10      7
Forest       20      5
FR Lake      30      2
Forest       40      3
```

I need to define area as key, count as value in dict. Thank you in advance.