# Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with four columns. I want to convert this DataFrame to a python dictionary. I want the elements of first column be `keys` and the elements of other columns in the same row be `values`.

DataFrame:

```py
    ID   A   B   C
0   p    1   3   2
1   q    4   3   2
2   r    4   0   9
```

Output should be like this:

```py
{'p': [1,3,2], 'q': [4,3,2], 'r': [4,0,9]}
```

Comment: `Dataframe.to_dict()`?

Comment: `Dataframe.to_dict()` will make `A,B,C` the keys instead of `p,q,r`

Comment: @jezrael how to get the following output? {2:{'p': [1,3]},2:{'q': [4,3]},9:{'r': [4,0]}} for the same dataset?

Comment: @jezrael column equivalents of the above question {'c':{'ID': 'A','B'}}

Comment: This question tackles one column only. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695605/python-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary

Answer (score 725, accepted):

The [`to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method sets the column names as dictionary keys so you'll need to reshape your DataFrame slightly. Setting the 'ID' column as the index and then transposing the DataFrame is one way to achieve this.

`to_dict()` also accepts an 'orient' argument which you'll need in order to output a *list* of values for each column. Otherwise, a dictionary of the form `{index: value}` will be returned for each column.

These steps can be done with the following line:

```
>>> df.set_index('ID').T.to_dict('list')
{'p': [1, 3, 2], 'q': [4, 3, 2], 'r': [4, 0, 9]}
```

---

In case a different dictionary format is needed, here are examples of the possible orient arguments. Consider the following simple DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'], 'b': [0.5, 0.25, 0.125]})
>>> df
        a      b
0     red  0.500
1  yellow  0.250
2    blue  0.125
```

Then the options are as follows.

**dict** - the default: column names are keys, values are dictionaries of index:data pairs

```
>>> df.to_dict('dict')
{'a': {0: 'red', 1: 'yellow', 2: 'blue'}, 
 'b': {0: 0.5, 1: 0.25, 2: 0.125}}
```

**list** - keys are column names, values are lists of column data

```
>>> df.to_dict('list')
{'a': ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'], 
 'b': [0.5, 0.25, 0.125]}
```

**series** - like 'list', but values are Series

```
>>> df.to_dict('series')
{'a': 0       red
      1    yellow
      2      blue
      Name: a, dtype: object, 

 'b': 0    0.500
      1    0.250
      2    0.125
      Name: b, dtype: float64}
```

**split** - splits columns/data/index as keys with values being column names, data values by row and index labels respectively

```
>>> df.to_dict('split')
{'columns': ['a', 'b'],
 'data': [['red', 0.5], ['yellow', 0.25], ['blue', 0.125]],
 'index': [0, 1, 2]}
```

**records** - each row becomes a dictionary where key is column name and value is the data in the cell

```
>>> df.to_dict('records')
[{'a': 'red', 'b': 0.5}, 
 {'a': 'yellow', 'b': 0.25}, 
 {'a': 'blue', 'b': 0.125}]
```

**index** - like 'records', but a dictionary of dictionaries with keys as index labels (rather than a list)

```
>>> df.to_dict('index')
{0: {'a': 'red', 'b': 0.5},
 1: {'a': 'yellow', 'b': 0.25},
 2: {'a': 'blue', 'b': 0.125}}
```

Comment: this will be one liner: `df.set_index('ID').T.to_dict('list')`

Comment: For one record in Data Frame.                                                            df.T.to_dict()[0]

Comment: `df.to_dict('records')` is how most modern software would want a dict that matches a `json` like pattern

Comment: yet here someone needs a alternation of 'index' method, one where its value of the dictionary is a pd.Series, meaning just breaking down the dataframe to a dictionaries of series, which can be achieved using `dict(list(df.iterrows()))` Enjoy!

Comment: sorry if this is a silly question, is there a best one for sharing (e.g. in giving an excerpt for a SE question)? Or is is there a 'best practice' for choosing which to use? thanks

Answer (score 169):

Should a dictionary like:

```
{'red': '0.500', 'yellow': '0.250', 'blue': '0.125'}
```

be required out of a dataframe like:

```
        a      b
0     red  0.500
1  yellow  0.250
2    blue  0.125
```

simplest way would be to do:

```
dict(df.values)
```

working snippet below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'], 'b': [0.5, 0.25, 0.125]})
dict(df.values)
```

Comment: Neat !  It only works for two-columns dataframes, though.

Answer (score 37):

## Follow these steps:

Suppose your dataframe is as follows:

```
>>> df
   A  B  C ID
0  1  3  2  p
1  4  3  2  q
2  4  0  9  r
```

#### 1. Use `set_index` to set `ID` columns as the dataframe index.

```
    df.set_index("ID", drop=True, inplace=True)
```

#### 2. Use the `orient=index` parameter to have the index as dictionary keys.

```
    dictionary = df.to_dict(orient="index")
```

The results will be as follows:

```
    >>> dictionary
    {'q': {'A': 4, 'B': 3, 'D': 2}, 'p': {'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'D': 2}, 'r': {'A': 4, 'B': 0, 'D': 9}}
```

#### 3. If you need to have each sample as a list run the following code. Determine the column order

```
column_order= ["A", "B", "C"] #  Determine your preferred order of columns
d = {} #  Initialize the new dictionary as an empty dictionary
for k in dictionary:
    d[k] = [dictionary[k][column_name] for column_name in column_order]
```

Comment: For the last bit seems you'd be simpler off using a dict comprehension to replace the for loop + list comprehension (3 lines -> 1). Either way, although it's nice to have options, the top answer is a lot shorter.

Comment: This on is handy because it explains clearly how to use a specific column or header as the index.

Answer (score 34):

Try to use `Zip`

```
df = pd.read_csv("file")
d= dict([(i,[a,b,c ]) for i, a,b,c in zip(df.ID, df.A,df.B,df.C)])
print d
```

Output:

```
{'p': [1, 3, 2], 'q': [4, 3, 2], 'r': [4, 0, 9]}
```

Answer (score 14):

If you don't mind the dictionary values being tuples, you can use itertuples:

```
>>> {x[0]: x[1:] for x in df.itertuples(index=False)}
{'p': (1, 3, 2), 'q': (4, 3, 2), 'r': (4, 0, 9)}
```

Answer (score 7):

For my use (node names with xy positions) I found @user4179775's answer to the most helpful / intuitive:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('glycolysis_nodes_xy.tsv', sep='\t')

df.head()
    nodes    x    y
0  c00033  146  958
1  c00031  601  195
...

xy_dict_list=dict([(i,[a,b]) for i, a,b in zip(df.nodes, df.x,df.y)])

xy_dict_list
{'c00022': [483, 868],
 'c00024': [146, 868],
 ... }

xy_dict_tuples=dict([(i,(a,b)) for i, a,b in zip(df.nodes, df.x,df.y)])

xy_dict_tuples
{'c00022': (483, 868),
 'c00024': (146, 868),
 ... }
```

---

**Addendum**

I later returned to this issue, for other, but related, work. Here is an approach that more closely mirrors the [excellent] accepted answer.

```
node_df = pd.read_csv('node_prop-glycolysis_tca-from_pg.tsv', sep='\t')

node_df.head()
   node  kegg_id kegg_cid            name  wt  vis
0  22    22       c00022   pyruvate        1   1
1  24    24       c00024   acetyl-CoA      1   1
...
```

**Convert Pandas dataframe to a [list], {dict}, {dict of {dict}}, ...**

Per accepted answer:

```
node_df.set_index('kegg_cid').T.to_dict('list')

{'c00022': [22, 22, 'pyruvate', 1, 1],
 'c00024': [24, 24, 'acetyl-CoA', 1, 1],
 ... }

node_df.set_index('kegg_cid').T.to_dict('dict')

{'c00022': {'kegg_id': 22, 'name': 'pyruvate', 'node': 22, 'vis': 1, 'wt': 1},
 'c00024': {'kegg_id': 24, 'name': 'acetyl-CoA', 'node': 24, 'vis': 1, 'wt': 1},
 ... }
```

In my case, I wanted to do the same thing but with selected columns from the Pandas dataframe, so I needed to slice the columns.  There are two approaches.

1. Directly:

(see: [Convert pandas to dictionary defining the columns used fo the key values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121620/convert-pandas-to-dictionary-defining-the-columns-used-fo-the-key-values))

```
node_df.set_index('kegg_cid')[['name', 'wt', 'vis']].T.to_dict('dict')

{'c00022': {'name': 'pyruvate', 'vis': 1, 'wt': 1},
 'c00024': {'name': 'acetyl-CoA', 'vis': 1, 'wt': 1},
 ... }
```

2. "Indirectly:" first, slice the desired columns/data from the Pandas dataframe (again, two approaches),

```
node_df_sliced = node_df[['kegg_cid', 'name', 'wt', 'vis']]
```

or

```
node_df_sliced2 = node_df.loc[:, ['kegg_cid', 'name', 'wt', 'vis']]
```

that can then can be used to create a dictionary of dictionaries

```
node_df_sliced.set_index('kegg_cid').T.to_dict('dict')

{'c00022': {'name': 'pyruvate', 'vis': 1, 'wt': 1},
 'c00024': {'name': 'acetyl-CoA', 'vis': 1, 'wt': 1},
 ... }
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that the Dataframe columns must be unique or they'll be omitted. Example would be if you have `c00022` for more than one row.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answers do not deal with the situation where ID can exist multiple times in the dataframe. In case `ID` can be duplicated in the Dataframe `df` you want to use a list to store the values (a.k.a a list of lists), grouped by `ID`:

```
{k: [g['A'].tolist(), g['B'].tolist(), g['C'].tolist()] for k,g in df.groupby('ID')}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary comprehension & iterrows() method could also be used to get the desired output.

```
result = {row.ID: [row.A, row.B, row.C] for (index, row) in df.iterrows()}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['p',1,3,2], ['q',4,3,2], ['r',4,0,9]], columns=['ID','A','B','C'])
my_dict = {k:list(v) for k,v in zip(df['ID'], df.drop(columns='ID').values)}
print(my_dict)
```

with output

```
{'p': [1, 3, 2], 'q': [4, 3, 2], 'r': [4, 0, 9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

##### If IDs are unique

`set_index().T.to_dict()` is a very simple syntax but transposing a dataframe is really slow. `dict(zip(...))` syntax is about 70 times faster. For example, for a frame with 1mil rows, `dict(zip(...))` takes less than 0.5sec while `set_index.T.to_dict` takes over 30sec.

```py
mydict = dict(zip(df['ID'], df.set_index('ID').values.tolist()))
```

Also a dict comprehension with `itertuples` is really fast (suggested by [Kamil Sindi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043453/19123103)) but about 3 times slower than `dict(zip(...))`.

```py
mydict = {x[0]: list(x[1:]) for x in df.itertuples(index=False)}
```

##### If IDs are duplicated

`itertuples` is especially useful if ID column has duplicate values. It's much faster to loop through the dataframe via `itertuples` and construct a dict using `dict.setdefault` than `groupby` (which was suggested by [Ka Wa Yip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70560967/19123103)) or `iterrows`. For example, for a dataframe with 100k rows and 60k unique IDs, `itertuples` is 250 times faster than `groupby`.<sup>1</sup>

```py
mydict = {}
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    mydict.setdefault(row[0], []).append(list(row[1:]))
```

###### Performance benchmarks:

As the runtime plot shows, `dict(zip(...))` and `itertuples` with `dict.setdefault` are much faster than their more "pandas" counterparts no matter how large the frames are.

[image: perfplot]

Code used to produce the above plots:

```py
import numpy as np
from perfplot import plot

plot(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.arange(n)}).join(pd.DataFrame(np.random.default_rng().choice(10, size=(n, 3)), columns=[*'ABC'])),
    kernels=[lambda df: dict(zip(df['ID'], df.set_index('ID').values.tolist())), 
             lambda df: df.set_index('ID').T.to_dict('list'), 
             lambda df: {x[0]: list(x[1:]) for x in df.itertuples(index=False)}],
    labels= ["dict(zip(df['ID'], df.set_index('ID').values.tolist()))", 
             "df.set_index('ID').T.to_dict('list')", 
             "{x[0]: list(x[1:]) for x in df.itertuples(index=False)}"],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(18)],
    xlabel='Number of rows',
    title='Unique IDs',
    equality_check=lambda x,y: x==y);


def itertuples_(df):
    mydict = {}
    for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
        mydict.setdefault(row[0], []).append(list(row[1:]))
    return mydict
        
def groupby_(df):
    return {k: g[['A', 'B', 'C']].values.tolist() for k, g in df.groupby('ID')}

plot(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame(np.random.default_rng().choice(n, size=(n, 4)), columns=['ID','A','B','C']),
    kernels=[itertuples_, groupby_],
    labels= ["itertuples", "groupby"],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(17)],
    xlabel="Number of rows",
    title="Duplicated IDs",
    equality_check=lambda x,y: x==y);
```

Answer (score 0):

With this method, columns of dataframe will be the keys and series of dataframe will be the values.`

```
data_dict = dict()
for col in dataframe.columns:
    data_dict[col] = dataframe[col].values.tolist()
```

Answer (score -1):

`DataFrame.to_dict()` converts DataFrame to dictionary.

**Example**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [0.5, 0.75]}, index=['a', 'b'])
>>> df
   col1  col2
a     1   0.1
b     2   0.2
>>> df.to_dict()
{'col1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'col2': {'a': 0.5, 'b': 0.75}}
```

See this [Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for details

Comment: Yes, but the OP explicitl stated they want the row indexes to be the keys, not the column labels.