# Reading csv file as dictionary using pandas

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have the foll. csv with 1st row as header:

```
A      B
test    23
try     34
```

I want to read in this as a dictionary, so doing this:

```
dt = pandas.read_csv('file.csv').to_dict()
```

However, this reads in the header row as key. I want the values in column 'A' to be the keys. How do I do that i.e. get answer like this:

```
{'test':'23', 'try':'34'}
```

Comment: So `{'A': ['test', 'try'], 'B': ['23', '34']}`?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, I want {'test':'23', 'try':'34'}. Updated question

Comment: And your delimiter is `\t`? Generally, `csv` files are `1, 2, 3\n4, 5, 6`. Commas and newlines to separate columns and rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Pandas DataFrame to dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary)

Comment: @RNar Nah, they look like completely different questions with different objects.

Comment: @Zizouz212 i will have to disagree with you. the inherent problem is that he wants to have a dict where the keys are the values in a column rather than the columns themselves. the answer to that is to set that column is the index of the dataframe then call `to_dict('list')`

Comment: @RNar Ah, but thats calling from a `pd.DataFrame` object, while this is from a `.csv` file, which are vastly different situations.

Comment: @Zizouz212 a `.csv` file which he is parsing as a pd.DataFrame with `pandas.read_csv`

Comment: @RNar Exactly, the questions are different, and therefore, the answers will be different as well. They need to be nearly identical to be considered duplicates.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
dt = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=1, skiprows=1).T.to_dict()
```

Comment: thanks @Alexander, your soln does not seem to work if any of the values are non-unique

Comment: why do you need the `.T`?

Comment: @Pinocchio It transposes the dataframe so that the index becomes the column names, i.e. the keys to the dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

Duplicating data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data="""
A      B
test    23
try     34
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), delimiter='\s+')
```

Converting to dictioanry:

```
print(dict(df.values))
```

Will give:

```
{'try': 34, 'test': 23}
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with what the op is asking, I'm just replicating his data

Comment: Then what makes you think this is a suitable answer?!?

Comment: All he needs is that `print(dict(df.values))` to get the output he needs.

Comment: But how is this reading from a `.csv` file? It's completely wrong.

Comment: He reads the file as a dataframe, then converts to dictionary. I'm not sure how else to put it.

Comment: Your answer is the simplest to replicate but a little difficult to understand for rookies.