# Convert column_names from a dataframe to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4

1             12          5           6
```

I want to create a dictionary with the column_name as keys i.e. Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4 and values as 1,2,3,4 (incremental values)

Post that, i want to transform my dataframe to below:

```
1             2          3             4

1             12          5           6
```

i.e. Column1 replaced by 1, Column2 replaced by 2 and so on......

Can someone help me out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary

Comment: What do you need the dict to look like?

Comment: If you just need last character as column names, `df.columns = df.columns.str[-1]`

Comment: I don't need the last characters, I just gave the column names as examples..i need to save the column names as a dictionary and replace the dataframe's column names with the dictionary values

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try this

```
d = {k: v for k, v in zip(df.columns, range(1, len(df.columns)+1))}    
Out[372]:
{'Column1': 1, 'Column2': 2, 'Column3': 3, 'Column4': 4}
```

After getting `d`, you can do

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().map(d).values

    1   2   3   4
0   1   12  5   6
```

Here we make use of [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and turn `df.columns` into a pd.Series object.

Comment: Didn't the op ask for some output without 'Column'?

Comment: @StephenRauch I am trying to follow the title...but good point.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a dictionary, you can assign `range` objects to `df.columns` directly.

```
df.columns = range(1, len(df.columns) + 1)

df
   1   2  3  4
0  1  12  5  6
```

---

You can also use any of the `.str` methods on `df.columns` -

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lstrip('Column')
```

Or,

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('^Column', '')
```

```
df
   1   2  3  4
0  1  12  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this codes will help you out:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [{'column1': 1, 'column2': 12,'column3': 15, 'column4': 6}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = range(1, len(df.columns) + 1)
print (df)
```

#the output goes like this :

```
df
   1   2  3  4
0  1  12  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd   
data = [{'column1': 1, 'column2': 12,'column3': 15, 'column4': 6}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#dict of columns {'column1': 1, 'column2': 2, ...}
column_dict = dict(zip(df.columns, list(range(len(df.columns))+1)))
# rename dataframe columns using rename method
new_df = df.rename(columns=column_dict)
```

Or this:

```
# create a df without specify columns names 
# will generate columns as numbers from 0 to len(df.columns) - 1
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.values)
# add 1 to starts by 1
new_df.columns = new_df.columns + 1
```