# python - How to get multiple key with single value for a dictionary from excel

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a excel sheet i.e,

```
   0 first     |second    |third      |root
   1 credible  |credulous |credibility|cred
   2 cryptogram|cryptology|cryptic    |crypt
   3 aquatic   |aquarium  |aqueduct   |aqua
```

i want to import key and value for dictionary from above mentioned excel sheet: 
for example:
 i have written a dictionary code for storing this values

```
   new_dict = {
    ('credible','credulous','credibility') : 'cred',
    ('cryptogram','cryptology','cryptic')   : 'crypt'
    }
```

so instead of writing key and value for each word in dictionary i want to import from excel where first 3 column(i.e first,second,third) should be the key and last column(i.e root) will be the value of a dictionary. Is it possible to do that?

sorry for my English.

Thanks

Comment: please post the code that you have written

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary this might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set the index for every column (first three, in this case) *besides* the `root`, and then call [`root.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df.set_index(df.columns.difference(['root']).tolist()).root.to_dict() 
{
    ('aquatic', 'aquarium', 'aqueduct')      : 'aqua',
    ('credible', 'credulous', 'credibility') : 'cred',
    ('cryptogram', 'cryptology', 'cryptic')  : 'crypt'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by first 3 columns with [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.set_index(['first','second','third'])['root'].to_dict()
print (d)
{('credible', 'credulous', 'credibility'): 'cred',
 ('aquatic', 'aquarium', 'aqueduct'): 'aqua', 
 ('cryptogram', 'cryptology', 'cryptic'): 'crypt'}
```