# Python - to_dict() creates unwanted nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Edit: the duplicate suggested was not able to resolve my issue as the indexed column is different from turning a normal df into a dict. Would appreciate it if the downvoter takes away the vote.

Very simple, I want to create a dictionary from a df, with the df indexes as keys, and a column called 'signal' as key-values. I've used the to_dict() method, however this produces a nested dictionary, rather than individual. Code:

```
df:

index             signal
james.mccallum    0
john.driscoe      1
...               ...
andrew.black      0

input:
score_dict = df.to_dict()

produces:
score_dict = {signal{james.mccallum: 0, john.driscoe: 1, ... andrew.black: 0}

desired:
score_dict = {james.mccallum: 0, john.driscoe: 1, ... andrew.black: 0}
```

I'm sure it's a simple fix, however have not been able to find anything related to what I want to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behavior of `to_dict` (check [this very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary) with inputs/outputs of the different possible args, followed with explanations on them).

In your case, just get all `signal` related values

```
>>> score_dict = df.to_dict()['signal']
{'james.mccallum': 0, 'john.driscoe': 1, 'andrew.black': 0}
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted. I'll mark your answer as correct when the timer allows for it. Thanks and have a good day mate.

Comment: @LaurieBamber glad I could help :)