# Pandas: filter data frame by category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set like below:

```
X, Y
yes, 1
No, 2
Yes, 3
Yes, 4
No, 2
No, 1
Yes, 0
No, 4
No, 4
No, 5
```

I want to get following output from it:

```
X: { Yes, No}
y: {[1, 3, 4, 0], [2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 5]}
```

How I can achieve using Python?

**EDIT**: I'm new to panda library, working as part of my data science project. How I can achieve this using panda dictionary.. can someone please give an example with the data set I have provided?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: @ Roul,  it can be achieved by pandas `groupby` with list comprehension, see my answer below..

Comment: @Roul,  Glad it works for you :)  happy learning

Comment: @cryptonome: if you don't have time to read the question properly or bother to answer it. please don't downgrade it. My question is totally different than the post and which is already answered.

Comment: @EdgarR.Mondragón: As I have mentioned I'm new to both Python and Panda library and still learning while working.. I have tried groupby and dictionary but couldn't find the exact solution.

Comment: as a matter of fact i didn't downvote you, if that's what you meant. i read your question & pointed there's an answered discussion where you can possibly find an answer about what you asked, as written there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas `groupby` method with list comprehension which will do the JOb like Below:

```
>>> df
     X  Y
0  Yes  1
1   No  2
2  Yes  3
3  Yes  4
4   No  2
5   No  1
6  Yes  0
7   No  4
8   No  4
9   No  5

>>> {k: v["Y"].tolist() for k,v in df.groupby("X")}
{'No': [2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 5], 'Yes': [1, 3, 4, 0]}
```