# Create a dictionary based on non unique column Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I havefound this answer [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary/26716774)
 which almost works for the following scenario, but I will explain why it does not.

example

```
nestedList = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C']]
df = pd.DataFrame(nestedList,columns=["1","2"])
```

Returns the following dataframe

```
   1  2
0  A  B
1  A  C
```

Which I would like to then use .to_dict() to convert to a dictionary with keys column 1 and list column 2

```
sampledict = {"A":["B","C"]}
```

using the linked example I set the column I would like to use as the key to column 1 and orient to list

```
sampledict = df.set_index('1').T.to_dict('list')
```

which returns

```
{'A': ['C']}
```

Because Dataframe columns are not unique once you transpose which is pointed out with the userwarning:

```
UserWarning: DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted.
```

Which is kind of confusing to me so I dug a bit deeper and found [Export pandas to dictionary by combining multiple row values](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32328/export-pandas-to-dictionary-by-combining-multiple-row-values) which I was able to modify to get the answer I wanted with the following code:

```
d = {}
for i in df["1"].unique():
    d[i] = [df["2"][j] for j in df[df["1"]==i].index]
```

Which returns

```
{'A': ['B', 'C']}
```

Which is great, however I still do not understand what it is that they did, as there was little explanation. Could a user please explain or write this in a more verbose manner? as well as potentially suggest a more simple solution?

Comment: `df.groupby('1')['2'].apply(list).to_dict()
`

Comment: Thanks this was actually really helpful, I did not see this