# Create a dictionary with dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Header = Category | US | UK | CA
Row 1 = A | value1 | value1 | value2
Row 2 = B | value2 | value1 | value3
Row 3 = C | value1 | value3 | value1
```

The column "category" contains unique values. The rest of the columns contain a value that can or cannot be unique. The way to read it is: for category A, US items have this value.

I am trying to create a dictionary so that keys are categories, and values are a dictionary with the countries as keys and the values as values.

```
Dict = {A : {US : value1, UK : value1, CA : value2}, B : 
{US:value2, UK:value1, CA:value3}, C : 
{US:value1,UK:value3,CA:value1}}
```

It's a long list, so I need to create it through iteration. I've been stuck with it all day. I get to create the keys correctly but I can get the "dictionary-values" right.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: is that the exact text table view? `Header = ` is actually presented as text?

Comment: What is a "table"

Comment: Are you trying to implement relational algebra? I implemented it here http://ltworf.github.io/relational/ and I uset python sets for tuples, so they must be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is an array of arrays:

```
table = [[ 'Category', 'US', 'UK', 'CA' ], [ 'A', 'value1', 'value1',  'value2'], [ 'B', 'value2', 'value1',  'value2']]

dict =  {table[i][0] :  {table[0][j]: table[i][j] for j in range(1,len(table[i]))} for i in range(1,len(table))}
print(dict)
```

Gives you:

> {'A': {'US': 'value1', 'UK': 'value1', 'CA': 'value2'}, 'B': {'US':
>   'value2', 'UK': 'value1', 'CA': 'value2'}}

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work and be easy enough to understand bascially just split on `" | "`:

```
import pprint


def main():
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
    path = "table.txt"
    res = {}
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        catagories = f.readline().strip().split(" | ")[-3:]
        for line in f:
            key_part, *values = line.strip().split(" | ")
            key = key_part.split()[-1]
            res[key] = {
                catagories[i]: values[i]
                for i in range(len(catagories))
            }
    pp.pprint(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**table.txt:**

```
Header = Category | US | UK | CA
Row 1 = A | value1 | value1 | value2
Row 2 = B | value2 | value1 | value3
Row 3 = C | value1 | value3 | value1
```

**Output:**

```
{ 
  'A': {'CA': 'value2', 'UK': 'value1', 'US': 'value1'},
  'B': {'CA': 'value3', 'UK': 'value1', 'US': 'value2'},
  'C': {'CA': 'value1', 'UK': 'value3', 'US': 'value1'}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I spent hours trying to figure out why creating a dictionary and then assigning it as another dictionary's value ended up with all resulting assignments being the same! I still can't figure it out. So I used your assigning using a live, unrolled (for ... in) { ..... } style. My attempt would have worked in perl. Curse you python!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas to dictionary [Pandas to Dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary), perhaps load from your text file to pandas and then convert to dict setting the index to Category.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",")
s = df.set_index('Category').T.to_dict('series')

print(s)
```

data.csv

```
Category,US,UK,CA
A,1,1,1
B,2,2,2
C,3,3,3
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to put values into a dictionary is to well, just assign them to a key:

```
dictionary[key] = v
```

Because you want to have dictionaries as values, you just need to write `{US : value1, UK : value1, CA : value2}` or something like that in the place of '`v`', with `value1, value2` and so on assigned the correct values.

And if you have US, UK and CA as strings and not variables with custom contents as keys in the inner dictionaries, write `"UK": value1` instead of `UK: value1`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is exactly as described in your question and is in the file `sapehi.txt`, this should do what you want.

```
f = open("sapehi.txt", "r")
first = f.readline()
table = first.split("=")[1] # Throw away the "Header =" part
columns = [x.strip() for x in table.split("|")][1:] # Create a list of the column headings

output = {} # Create the output dictionary

while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if (line == ""): # If there's no more data in the file, exit the loop
        break
    row = line.split("=")[1] # Throw away the "Row x" part
    values = [x.strip() for x in row.split("|")] # Create a row elements
    category = values[0] # Category is the first row element
    values = values[1:] # The values are all the rest
    output[category] = {} # Create a dict for this category
    for index, value in enumerate(values):
        output[category][columns[index]] = value # Populate it with the values

print(output)
```

This script gets the column headers into a list, which is accessed for each row.