# How to convert DF to Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Here is mycode:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

p=pd.read_excel("D:\contacts.xlsx")
pp=p.set_index('Col-A').T
print(pp)
dic=pp.to_dict()

print(dic)
```

My DF :

```
    Col-A  Col-B
0      1     10
1      2     20
2      3     30
3      4     40
4      5     50
5      6     60
6      7     70
7      8     80
8      9     90
9     10    100
```

**Expected output : 
`{1:10,2:20,3:30,4:40,5:50}`**

My output looks like:

```
Col-A  1   2   3   4   5 
Col-B  10  20  30  40  50  
{1: {'Col-B': 10}, 2: {'Col-B': 20}, 3: {'Col-B': 30}, 4: {'Col-B': 40}, 5: {'Col-B': 50}}
```

How can i achieve the expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

First `set_index` and then do `to_dict` and call `Col-B`

```
df.set_index('Col-A').to_dict()['Col-B']

# {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60, 7: 70, 8: 80, 9: 90, 10: 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

The to_dict method receives a parameter "orient" and the default value is dict.

You can transform this output setting the orient to "list".

```
df.to_dict('list')
```

You can iterate after this to flat your list into single value.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html