# Convert each column of a DataFrame into a dictionary and name the dictionary based on column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

*I have a DataFrame named distinct_values:*

```
   gender      purchase_frequency

0  Female                Low

1    Male                Mid

2    Male               High

3  Female                Mid

4  Female               High

5    Male                Low
```

*I now want to convert each column of this dataframe into a dictionary where name of the dictionary is based on column name:*

```
gender={'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male'}
purchase_frequency= {'Low', 'Mid', 'High', 'Mid', 'High', 'Low'}
```

*I have tried the following method but this combined the dataframe to a single dictionary of lists and that wasn't desired:*

```
df_dict = dict(zip([i for i in distinct_values.columns] , [pd.DataFrame(distinct_values[i].unique(), columns=[i]) for i in distinct_values.columns]))
```

Please let me know if there is a solution to this

Comment: Those are not dictionaries

Comment: `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for col_name in distinct_values:
    exec(f'{col_name} = {dict(distinct_values[col_name])}')
print(gender)
print(purchase_frequency)
```

the result will be: 
gender = {0: 'Female', 1: 'Male', 2: 'Male', 3: 'Female', 4: 'Female', 5: 'Male'} 
purchase_frequency = {0: 'Low', 1: 'Mid', 2: 'High', 3: 'Mid', 4: 'High', 5: 'Low'}