# Create Dictionary From Dataframe Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to create a dictionary where the keys are values from one column of a data frame and the values are from another column in the corresponding row.

So here is an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.head()

    A   B   C   D
0   34  99  78  0
1   31  47  44  22
2   53  38  11  27
3   86  84  81  87
4   57  4   23  46
```

And I want to get a dictionary like this, with the A values as the keys and the C values as the dictionary values:

```
{34: 78, 31: 44, 53: 11, 86: 81,57: 23}
```

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a dict from an array of tuples with keys and tuples. So you can use the dict constructor straightforward here after converting the values to tuples with the `zip` function

```
In [12]: dict(zip(df['A'], df['C']))                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[12]: {34: 78, 31: 44, 53: 11, 86: 81, 57: 23}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Another approach** [`Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```
df.set_index('A')['C'].to_dict()
# {34: 78, 31: 44, 53: 11, 86: 81, 57: 23}
```