# Dataframe to Dictionary of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have got a data-frame with the following values:

```
Location   ID
DS         12973
DS         12955
DS         12947
St. paul   12949
Bakersfield 12097
Vernon     12905
vernon     12096
vernon     12902
```

and so on

I want to convert it into a dictionary in the following way, can anyone please help:

```
{
'DS':[12973, 12955, 12947]
'St.Paul':[12949, 12955]
'Bakersfield, CA': [ 12097]
'Vernon': [12905, 12906, 12902, 12927, 12900, 12915]
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary) will help?

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt work for me

Comment: @amanvarma - People here take a lot of time out from their own schedules to assist others on SO, A good way to thanks & support any help you receive on SO is to upvote/mark the correct answer on your question. This not only motivates them to continue helping but also lets others, who face similar question, get a the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (`groupby` location and get ID as a `list`, then convert to `dict`)-

```
df['Location'] = df['Location'].str.lower() #This is because Vernon and vernon both exist, one with a capital V and another with a lower case v.

df.groupby('Location')['ID'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

```
{'bakersfield': [12097],
 'ds': [12973, 12955, 12947],
 'st. paul': [12949],
 'vernon': [12905, 12096, 12902]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, akshay. Highly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

another way to solve this is to use `groupby`

```
df['Location'] = df.Location.str.lower()
{loc: list(grp.ID) for loc, grp in df.groupby('Location')}
```