# How to grab all data from dataframe column into a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Lets say I have a dataframe like this:

```
     first|second|
1      a  |   123|
2      b  |   234|
3      a  |    23|
4      b  |     1|
5      c  |    53|
6      a  |    32|
```

and I'd like to have a dict like this:
dict = {'a': [123, 23, 32], 'b':[234, 1], 'c':[53]}

I have thought to use groupby but couldn't figure out how.
I know it should be a for loop somehow:
add every element from the first column as keys
add every element from the second column to the keys they match.

Comment: pandas have a to_dict method.

Comment: check out the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26716774/13261176

Answer (score 2):

Group by first column `1` and then do aggregation of column `2` to a list. Then `.to_dict()`:

```
print( df.groupby('1')['2'].agg(list).to_dict() )
```

Prints:

```
{'a': [123, 78, 987], 'b': [56, 21], 'c': [1]}
```