# Read the keys and values from the columns of a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a csv file that has two columns. One for the timeslot and one for the Energy. I put this file into pandas dataframe and I have attached the screenshot of this.[image: Screenshot of datafrmae]

Now I would like to have dictionary that has as the key values the entries from one column and as the values the entries from the other column. I tried all the options mentioned here [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary) but it was not successfull. Here you can see my code and my tried. I indicated the desired dictionary:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import pandas as pd


#Define the model

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()


#Define the sets

model.set_timeslots = pyo.RangeSet(0,95)



# Read the data for the parameters from a csv file
dataframe = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/energy.csv", sep =";")

dictionary_dict = dataframe.to_dict('dict')
dictionary_list = dataframe.to_dict('list')
dictionary_series = dataframe.to_dict('series')
dictionary_split = dataframe.to_dict('split')

desiredDictionary = {'t0':7696850, 't1':7765100 , 't2': 7833350}
```

Can you tell me how I can automatically create this desired dataframe? I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
d = dataframe.head(3).set_index('Timeslot')['Energy'].to_dict()
```

If need all values:

```
d1 = dataframe.set_index('Timeslot')['Energy'].to_dict()
```

EDIT:

If need 2 dimensional key - tuple use:

```
d = dataframe.head(3).set_index(['Timeslot', 'household'])['Energy'].to_dict
```

---

```
d1 = dataframe.set_index(['Timeslot', 'household'])['Energy'].to_dict()
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael for your answer. Basically it works. Maybe one follow up question. What if I wanted to have a 2 dimensional key (in this case the dataframe should have 3 columns). How could I implement this

Comment: @PeterBe - How should looks dict? Do you need `dataframe.head(3).set_index('Timeslot').to_dict()` ?

Comment: Yes basically your answer is correct for my case. I was just wondering if I had a csv file with 3 columns e.g. Timeslot, household, Energy and I would like to have a dictionary with the 2-dimensional key (timeslot, household): Energy. How would this look like

Comment: Is this possible to have a 2-dimensional key?

Comment: Cool, thanks jezrael for your help. I really appreciate it. I upvoted and accepted your answer.