# How to convert a dataframe to a dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
      Factors    low   high
0      amount    2.5      4
1  grind_size      8     10
2   brew_time    3.5    4.5
3  grind_type   burr  blade
4       beans  light   dark
```

and I want to make following dict:

```
lows = { 'amount' : 2.5,
         'grind_size' : 8,
         'brew_time': 3.5,
         'grind_type': 'burr',
         'beans': 'light' }
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

You can get this dict with

```
dict(zip(df['Factors'], df['low']))
```

or

```
df.set_index('Factors')['low'].to_dict()
```