# How to turn a df into a dictionary of lists consisting of index values in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `df` that ranks players by week (represented by each column)

```
   1    2    3    4
0 Bob  Jim  Pam  Pam
1 Amy  Amy  Jim  Bob
2 Jim  Bob  Bob  Amy
3 Pam  Pam  Amy  Jim
```

For example, `Bob` ranks 1st in week 1, 3rd in week 2, etc... I would like to turn this `df` into a dictionary that consists of a list of numeric ranks (ie the index value for each week) for each player, like so:

```
{'Bob': [1,
  3,
  3,
  2],
 'Jim': [3,
  1,
  2,
  4],
 'Pam': [4,
  4,
  1,
  1],
 'Amy': [2,
  2,
  4,
  3]}
```

I know I can do something with `index` to get each team's index for each week, but first I would need to

1. Shift the index so it starts at 1 (I was able to do this with `df.index += 1`)
2. Make a key for each team with the value pair being a list of their ranks

I am pretty stumped on part 2 but there has to be a pretty simple solution to this that I am missing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable, and is likely a violation of your school's academic honesty policies.

Comment: This is a personal project and have genuinely attempted this for an hour. I'm stuck and figured I'd ask for help. @Prune

Comment: That certainly removes any worries about academic policies.  However, the underlying principle still applies.  ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Would it help if I edited the question and included the code I tried to solve this problem with? Like I said, I've genuinely attempted this and am stuck, which is what I thought this site is for. @Prune

Comment: "Would it help ...?"  Yes.  Again, please refer to the posting guidelines; I've given several links.

Answer (score 3):

We can transpose with `T` and `stack` to get rank in a column as an index, then swap indexes and values in a new dataframe, `groupby` and `apply(list)` to get all ranks for each person as a list, and finally convert to dictionary with `to_dict`:

```
s = df.T.stack().droplevel(0)
pd.DataFrame(
    s.index + 1,
    index=s.values).groupby(level=0)[0].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'Amy': [2, 2, 4, 3],
 'Bob': [1, 3, 3, 2],
 'Jim': [3, 1, 2, 4],
 'Pam': [4, 4, 1, 1]}
```

Answer (score 2):

First use `.unstack.reset_index(-1)` to combine all the columns in one column. Then `groupby` using the column containing player name and then use aggregate with list function.

Use:

```
stacked_df = df.unstack().reset_index(-1)
stacked_df.level_1 += 1
>>> stacked_df
     level_1    0
1        1  Bob
1        2  Amy
1        3  Jim
1        4  Pam
2        1  Jim
...
3        4  Amy
4        1  Pam
4        2  Bob
4        3  Amy
4        4  Jim

out = stacked_df.groupby([0])['level_1'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
{'Amy': [2, 2, 4, 3], 'Bob': [1, 3, 3, 2],
'Jim': [3, 1, 2, 4], 'Pam': [4, 4, 1, 1]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rank = dict()

for col in df.columns:
  for element in df[col]:
    if element not in rank.keys():
      rank[element] =[]
      rank[element].append(df[col].to_list().index(element)+1)
    else:
      rank[element].append(df[col].to_list().index(element)+1)

print(rank)

{'Bob': [1, 3, 3, 2],
 'Jim': [3, 1, 2, 4],
 'Pam': [4, 4, 1, 1],
 'Amy': [2, 2, 4, 3] }
```