# Converting dataframe to dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Jhp.png)
I have one example dataframe above, I was wondering is it possible that it can be converted into something like below. If yes, do enlighten me. Thanks in advance!

expected_output

```
{
 "items":[{"outlet":"Outlet A","count":"11","amount":"22"},
      {"outlet":"Outlet B","count":"22","amount":"33"},
      {"outlet":"Outlet C","count":"33","amount":"44"}],
 "merchant":"Merchant A"
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey I wrote this and it works, you can modify it as you like although I'm sure it's not fully optimized.

```
datdict={'items':[],'merchant':[]}
for i,a,b,c in zip(df.merchant,df.outlet,df.counted,df.amount):
    datdict['items'].append(dict(outlet=a,counted=b,amount=c))
    if i not in datdict['merchant']:
        datdict['merchant'].append(i)
```