# Convert dataframe to dictionary in a custom order

Tags: python

How can I convert the below dataframe to a dictionary where the key is values of 'node' and the value is values of 'label'?

```
   label   node
0   False   254
1   False   255
2   False   256
3   False   260
4   False   261
```

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61614795/7867968)?

Comment: This is already answered here:
[convert a pandas dataframe to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: It is already answered here:
[convert a pandas dataframe to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `zip` the two columns together:

```py
>>> dict(zip(df["node"], df["label"]))
{254: False, 255: False, 256: False, 260: False, 261: False}
```