# How to convert cells in a row from a dataframe to a dictionary using a loop on Python? Pandas related

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

Let's say I have the following `df`:

```
       0      0      1               1    2       2     3        3      4    4    5     5         
0  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas None            
1  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Arena     
2  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Marron    
3  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Purpura    
4  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Verde
```

I know I can use [`Series.iteritems`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html) this way to iterate over a particular row in this `df` and print the content of each cell in a particular row (ignoring the index column):

```
row = 0 #desired row
for _, e in df.iloc[row].iteritems():
    print(e)
```

**Output:**

> Fondo
>
> Oceano
>
> Cuerpo
>
> Cuerpo cangrejo
>
> Ojos
>
> Antenas
>
> Color
>
> Amarillo
>
> Pinzas
>
> None
>
> Puas
>
> None

But what I need like to learn now is how could I improve the loop above so that it creates a dictionary that has *even cells* as `keys` and *odd cells* as `values` respectively?

In other words, how could I get the following dictionary for the `0` row as output?

```
the_dic = { 'Fondo':'Oceano',
            'Cuerpo': 'Cuerpo cangrejo',
            'Ojos': 'Antenas',
            'Color': 'Amarillo',
            'Pinzas': 'None',
            'Puas': 'None'
          }
```

*PS: The '**None**' element in this case is a `str` value and not the object `None`*

Comment: Looking for this ?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Solution working if 2 duplicated values in columns names like in sample data:

```
print (df.columns)
Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5], dtype='int64')
```

You can loop by indices with convert first and second values in dict comprehension:

```
row = 0
d = {x.iat[0]: x.iat[1] for name, x in df.iloc[row].groupby(level=0)}
print (d)
{'Fondo': 'Oceano', 'Cuerpo': 'Cuerpo cangrejo', 'Ojos': 'Antenas', 'Color': 'Amarillo', 'Pinzas': 'None', 'Puas': 'None'}
```

Or filter first and last indices and add `zip` with `dict`:

```
row = 0
s = df.iloc[row]

d = dict(zip(s[~s.index.duplicated()], s[~s.index.duplicated(keep='last')]))
print (d)
{'Fondo': 'Oceano', 'Cuerpo': 'Cuerpo cangrejo', 'Ojos': 'Antenas', 'Color': 'Amarillo', 'Pinzas': 'None', 'Puas': 'None'}
```

For testing:

```
s = pd.Series(['Fondo', 'Oceano', 'Cuerpo', 'Cuerpo cangrejo', 'Ojos', 
               'Antenas', 'Color', 'Amarillo', 'Pinzas', 'None', 'Puas', 'None'],
              index=[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5])
print (s)
0              Fondo
0             Oceano
1             Cuerpo
1    Cuerpo cangrejo
2               Ojos
2            Antenas
3              Color
3           Amarillo
4             Pinzas
4               None
5               Puas
5               None
dtype: object

d = dict(zip(s[~s.index.duplicated(keep='last')], s[~s.index.duplicated()]))
print (d)
{'Oceano': 'Fondo', 'Cuerpo cangrejo': 'Cuerpo', 'Antenas': 'Ojos', 'Amarillo': 'Color', 'None': 'Puas'}
```

Comment: Hmph, I tried the first one and I got the following error:  `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`, and second one creates a dictionary with the same `keys` as `values` for every cell in the row :(

Comment: @NoahVerner - are there columns names duplicated? What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: Yes, the name of the columns are duplicated :( @jezreal

Comment: I get the warning `Undefined name Int64Index` after typing `Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5], dtype='int64')`, did I forget to import any module?

Comment: @NoahVerner - You can use `df.columns=[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]`

Comment: Or `s.index=[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]`

Comment: Thank you sir, after adding `df_metadata.columns=[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]` right above the second solution you provided the program printed what I needed :), I appreciate it.