# python - dataframe columns into dict of dicts

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe like:

```
subject   score_A   score_B   score_C
math        90        75        50
art         85        65        45
econ        90        80        60
```

I want to make them into a dict like:

```
{
   'math':{'A': 90,
           'B': 75,
           'C': 50},
   'art': {'A': 85,
           'B': 65,
           'C': 45},
   'econ':{'A': 90,
           'B': 80,
           'C': 60},
}
```

The actual dataframe is much longer and a bit wider (with more keys for each subject than A, B, and C).

I suppose this has something to do with generating list of lower-level keys like A, B, C, etc and using the `zip` function but none of my limited tries worked.

Comment: set subject as index and try to call `.to_dict(orient="index")` on your Dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `subject` as index and then use `to_dict` with `orient` param -

```
df.set_index('subject').to_dict(orient='index')
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! This is so convenient. But I still wonder if we could achieve this by using something like ```dict(zip(.....))``` (if it's possible and not too complicated)

Answer (score 2):

You can first generate a list of dictionaries and then use zip to construct the final dictionary.

```
dict(zip(df["subject"], [dict(df.iloc[i, 1:]) for i in range(len(df))]))
```

Of course a bit ugly to loop over the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use to_dict(). you can find the answer in the below link

[Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Use [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) before converting the DataFrame [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

```
df.set_index("subject").T.to_dict()
```