# Converting Dataframe to Dict and Sending to API

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe that I need to convert to a dict and send via API as Json.

This is my df:

| Category | Topic | Steps | Stud1 | Stud2 | Stud3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cat1 | topc1 | step1 | 10 | 15 | 30 |
| Cat1 | topc2 | step2 | 16 | 26 | 42 |
| Cat3 | topc3 | step3 | 05 | 62 | 50 |

I want to generate dict something like this:

```
{Cat1: {
        topc1:{
               step1:
                     [
                       {Stud1:10},
                       {Stud2:15},
                       {Stud3:30}
                     ]
               }
        }
        topc2:{
               step2:
                     [
                       {Stud1:10},
                       {Stud2:15},
                       {Stud3:30}
                     ]
               }
        }
}
```

I know I can achieve this with for loop and `iterrows()` but that would be slow result.

I have tried using `to_dict()` function from pandas with `group_by()` on Category, Topic, Step but that doesn't give required output. I have tried many ways like `stack()` and I even merging the rows of same name but it yields no result. Can anyone tell me best efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)?

Comment: @ErselEr Yes, I tried all orients from `to_dict()`. But the result I want is too complex for `to_dict()` predefined methods. have to resolve with custom methods only.

Comment: Could there be duplicate `Topic`-`Steps` for a single `Category`? For example, could the `Topic` value in the 2. row be equal to `topic1` and the `Step`-value in the 2. row be equal to `step1` at the same time?

Comment: @Timus Yes, In such case relation should be `topic: step1, step2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I understand the question fully. But you could try this:

```
result = {}
for (key1, key2, key3), sdf in df.groupby(["Category", "Topic", "Steps"]):
    inner = result.setdefault(key1, {}).setdefault(key2, {})
    inner[key3] = [
        {key: value}
        for record in sdf[["Stud1", "Stud2", "Stud3"]].to_dict(orient="records")
        for key, value in record.items()
    ]
```

Result for your example `df`:

```
{'Cat1': {'topc1': {'step1': [{'Stud1': 10}, {'Stud2': 15}, {'Stud3': 30}]},
          'topc2': {'step2': [{'Stud1': 16}, {'Stud2': 26}, {'Stud3': 42}]}},
 'Cat3': {'topc3': {'step3': [{'Stud1': 5}, {'Stud2': 62}, {'Stud3': 50}]}}}
```

This, more direct, variation is bit faster, but not much:

```
result = {}
for (key1, key2, key3), sdf in df.groupby(["Category", "Topic", "Steps"]):
    inner = result.setdefault(key1, {}).setdefault(key2, {})
    inner[key3] = [
        {key: value}
        for values in zip(sdf["Stud1"], sdf["Stud2"], sdf["Stud3"])
        for key, value in zip(("Stud1", "Stud2", "Stud3"), values)
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you. This method works. Just a question though is there any way we can speed up process. As doing this loop on my dataset is quite slow.

Comment: @SahilMohile I've experimented a bit but couldn't come up with a major performance improvement -- sorry :(

Comment: Its okay. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

```
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    return str({k:v for d in ss.tolist() for k,v in d.items()})

df.groupby(['Category','Topic','Steps']).apply(lambda dd:dd[['Stud1','Stud2','Stud3']].to_dict('r'))\
    .reset_index(level=2).apply(lambda ss:{ss.iloc[0]:ss.iloc[1]},axis=1)\
    .reset_index(level=1).apply(lambda ss:{ss.iloc[0]:ss.iloc[1]},axis=1)\
    .groupby(level=0).apply(function1).map(eval).to_dict()
```

out：

```
{'Cat1': {'topc1': {'step1': [{'Stud1': 10, 'Stud2': 15, 'Stud3': 30}]},
  'topc2': {'step2': [{'Stud1': 16, 'Stud2': 26, 'Stud3': 42}]}},
 'Cat3': {'topc3': {'step3': [{'Stud1': 5, 'Stud2': 62, 'Stud3': 50}]}}}
```