# How to Create a nested dictionary, from excel data using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

using Excel table data, Want to create a nested dictionary as follows:

```
    dict_mainmenu_items = {"id"     : {"lbl101":"file"   ,"lbl102":"accounts"  ,"lbl103":"inventory","lbl104":"manufacture"},
                           "english" : {"lbl101":"File"  ,"lbl102":"Accounts"  ,"lbl103":"Inventory","lbl104":"Manufacture"},
                           "tamil"   : {"lbl101":"tamil_file","lbl102":"tamil_accounts","lbl103":"tamil_inventory","lbl104":"tamil_manu"},
                           "hindi"   : {"lbl101":"hindi_file","lbl102":"hindi_accounts","lbl103":"hindi_inventory","lbl104":"hindi_manuf"}}
```

try to solve the problem by using pandas, and code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = r'C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Documents/pyhton_dict_example.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
df.set_index('lbl_name',inplace=True)

print(df.to_dict(orient='index'))
```

its produce the following result :

```
{'lbl101': {'id': 'file', 'english': 'File', 'tamil': 'tamil_file', 'hindi': 'Hindi_File'}, 'lbl102': {'id': 'accounts', 'english': 'Accounts', 'tamil': 'tamil_accounts', 'hindi': 'Hindi_Accounts'}, 'lbl103': {'id': 'inventory', 'english': 'Inventory', 'tamil': 'tamil_inventory', 'hindi': 'Hindi_Inventory'}, 'lbl104': {'id': 'manufacture', 'english': 'Manufacture', 'tamil': 'tamil_manuf', 'hindi': 'Hindi_Manufacture'}}
```

**Excel Table**

| lbl_name | id | english | tamil | hindi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lbl101 | file | File | tamil_file | hindi_file |
| lbl102 | accounts | Accounts | tamil_accounts | hindi_accounts |
| lbl103 | inventory | Inventory | tamil_inventory | hindi_inventory |
| lbl104 | manufacture | Manufacture | tamil_manufact | hindi_manu |

```
| lbl_name | id         |english     |tamil            |hindi          |
|------------------------------------------------------|---------------|
| lbl101   | file       | File       |tamil_File       |hindi_file     |
| lbl102   | accounts   | Accounts   |tamil_accounts   |hindi+accounts |          |
| lbl103   | inventory  | Inventory  |tamil_inventory  |hindi_inventory|
| lbl104   | manufacture| Manufacture|tamil_manufact|  |hindi_manu     |
```

Comment: isn't only `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: whats wrong with your current code? what does it currently give you?

Comment: Does the [`df.to_dict` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) answer your question? Also, please take time to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Don't use `orient='index'`, leave it as it is by default: `orient='dict'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: @Vladimir Fokow, goat a solution from ignatius Reilly  comment,as above

Answer (score 0):

you should transpose the dataframe before converting it into dictionary.

```
df.T.to_dict()
```