# Should all python dict types be type hinted to dict?

Tags: python, pandas, type-hinting

Excuse my noob question as I haven't done too much python coding so am not as familiar with "pythonic" ways and untyped languages.

In Python I see the `Dataframe.to_dict()` method has several ways it can return the dict. For example, `Dataframe.to_dict("records")` basically returns a list.

My question is, should the return type of this be type hinted to `list` or `dict`? Afaik `type hinting` has no runtime effect. And `Dataframe.to_dict("records")` is basically a list except for the fact that it calls `Dataframe.to_dict()`, so it'd stand to reason that it'd make more sense if I treat it as a list. But officially it's a `dict`

Comment: "But officially it's a `dict`" - no it's not.

Comment: You should probably clarify you're refering to the Pandas `DataFrame.to_dict()` method.

Comment: Wait, Pandas has a function called `to_dict` that can return a *list*? .... .... .... just why.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It converts each record in the DataFrame to a dict, and returns you a list of all of those dicts.  See the first link in my answer for a breakdown of the possible formats, although that post doesn't yet include the new "tight" option.

Comment: As for why you might want a list of dicts for the DataFrame, it allows you to process and manipulate the data like JSON. Pandas has a `to_json()` method as well, but that just returns everything as a JSONified string, so you need to use `to_dict()` if you want to manipulate the data.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety thanks you're right, I clarified it's `DataFrame.to_dict()` and thanks for the explanations! 

@SilvioMayolo I was equally confused as to why it can return a list but the explanation below makes sense. Definitely not something I'm used to.

Comment: @Kevin  The justification for why `to_dict()` has this one case of returning a list of dicts, is that every orient option in `to_dict()` directly correlates to the same option in `to_json()`. In the Python paradigm, it would be more confusing to have a separate method specifically for the "records" option, and having a separate method for each possible orientation just to keep your return types looking simpler is equally frustrating.  Perhaps `to_collection()` would be more technically correct, but all of the options include dicts at the first or second level of the collection.

Comment: I completely agree with @SilvioMayolo. The fact that the method is called `to_dict` and it can return a list is laughable. One of the many questionable Pandas design decisions. And the claim that this somehow corresponds to _"the Python paradigm"_ is even more questionable, to say the least. Maybe the "Pandas paradigm"... There is nothing frustrating about designing simple and clear-cut interfaces that **do one thing and do it well**. What is frustrating is _bloated_ library interfaces that are so inconsistent, you basically never know what you're going to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataFrame.to_dict()`  returns a  `list[dict]`, in the case of orient = "records".
For the other formats, the it returns a dict for which the values could be dict, list, list[list], or Series. The accepted answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary) has a good breakdown of the possible outputs.

Pandas's [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) lists the return type as:
`dict, list or collections.abc.Mapping`

If you wanted to add a type hint for the return of the `Dataframe.to_dict()` method and be more thorough, then you could use the following as of Python 3.10

```
def to_dict(orient: str, into: collections.abc.Mapping, index: bool) -> dict[str, dict] | dict[str, list] | dict[str, Series] | dict[str, list] | list[dict] | dict[int, dict]:
```

I'm not sure even that covers every possible combination, which is why using `dict | list | collections.abc.Mapping` would be more than sufficient, with additional documentation explaining the different outputs based on the value of the orient argument.
In Python, type hints do not prevent a script from running as a type mismatch in a strictly typed language would do. It's meant to help point out potential issues in your code and provide some assistance, but its not a hard stop. Parameter type hints are generally more important than return type hints as passing the wrong data type as a parameter is more likely to cause an exception to be raised.

Comment: _Parameter type hints are generally more important than return type hints as passing the wrong data type as a parameter is more likely to cause an exception to be raised._ And returning `Any` makes the rest of the code using the function a raffle. "Place your bets, ladies and gentlemen! What might this function return? Maybe a list? Maybe a dictionary? Maybe something else entirely?" I mean, I too like to live dangerously. But I guess sometimes I just like to, you know, _know ahead of time_ what type I get out of a function. But that is just me.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg.  Clearly, if a return type can be specified, it should be, and `Any` should almost never be used a type hint.  In its place, if necessary, you should generally be using `object`. However that can also be overly restrictive in some cases.   The return value of `to_dict()` is a dict unless you as the consumer specify `orient="records"`, so you presumably know what  you're getting as output in that case.