# Pandas converting data frame into nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of the following format

`User    Movie  Rating 
   1      hp1       4
   1      hp2       5
   2      lor       2
   3       sw       2
   3      sw2       4
   3      sw3       5`

I want a dictionary in the format

```
{ 1 : { hp1:4,hp2:5},
  2:  { lor:2},
  3:  { sw:2,sw2:4,sw3:5}
}
```

I came across few answers like this which deals only with two columns: [python pandas dataframe to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695605/python-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary)

Closest answer is an recursion based approach i found in one of the questions:

```
def recur_dictify(frame):
if len(frame.columns) == 1:
    if frame.values.size == 1: return frame.values[0][0]
    return frame.values.squeeze()
grouped = frame.groupby(frame.columns[0])
d = {k: recur_dictify(g.ix[:,1:]) for k,g in grouped}
return d
```

But when i run this piece of code on a dataframe with million rows then it takes too much time.

I want to know is there a efficient approach to my problem in hand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Edchum i have seen some of those answers . The example i have given is just sample i have a dataset of million records on which i have to perform this perform.if you can provide a efficient solution it will be helpful

Comment: Then you need to update your question and add what you're trying to achieve and why those answers don't satisfy your question, so you need to spell out how your situation is different