# Convert a pandas dataframe into a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in which I have attributes and values for two products.

```
PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE   VALUES
prod1   Attr1         A
prod1   Attr2         B
prod1   Attr3         C
prod1   Attr4         D
prod2   Attr1         E
prod2   Attr2         F
prod2   Attr3         G
prod2   Attr4         H
```

How can I convert it into a dictionary of a list of dictionaries that looks like the following?

```
{'prod1':[{'Attr1':A, 'Attr2':B, 'Attr3':C, 'Attr4':D}], 'prod2':[{'Attr1':E, 'Attr2':F, 'Attr3':G, 'Attr4':H}]}
```

Comment: can you show what you've tried

Comment: You need to pivot the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas dataframe to dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695605/python-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary)

Comment: @ChrisBeard my question is different, I know how to use to_dict() function but this problem requires some kind of pivot first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply`:

```
d = df.groupby('PRODUCT').apply(lambda x: [dict(zip(x.ATTRIBUTE, x.VALUES))]).to_dict()
print (d)
{'prod1': [{'Attr1': 'A', 'Attr2': 'B', 'Attr3': 'C', 'Attr4': 'D'}],
'prod2': [{'Attr1': 'E', 'Attr2': 'F', 'Attr3': 'G', 'Attr4': 'H'}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to prepare your data and then call [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
>>> df.pivot(columns='PRODUCT',index='ATTRIBUTE', values='VALUES').to_dict()
{'prod1': {'Attr4': 'D', 'Attr2': 'B', 'Attr3': 'C', 'Attr1': 'A'}, 'prod2': {'Attr4': 'H', 'Attr2': 'F', 'Attr3': 'G', 'Attr1': 'E'}}
```

I also assume that you don't actually need one-element lists there. In this case you can have really simple solution. If you need those lists then it's probably better to go with @jezrael answer

Comment: Very Cool! Thanks a lot for this answer. Working amazing!

Answer (score 2):

comprehension

```
{k: [v.to_dict()] for k, v in df.set_index(['PRODUCT', 'ATTRIBUTE']).VALUES.unstack(0).iteritems()}

{'prod1': [{'Attr1': 'A', 'Attr2': 'B', 'Attr3': 'C', 'Attr4': 'D'}],
 'prod2': [{'Attr1': 'E', 'Attr2': 'F', 'Attr3': 'G', 'Attr4': 'H'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot and use the to_dict method and then wrap the inner dict in a list.

```
d= df.pivot(index='PRODUCT', columns='ATTRIBUTE', values='VALUES').to_dict()
{key:[value] for key,value in d.items()}
```