# Pandas dataframe to dict on multiple columns and values to list

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
id    key
a1     1
a2     1
a3     1
a4     2
a5     2
a6     3
```

I want to create a dictionary with `key` as machine no, and `id` column as list

like:

```
{1: ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 2: ['a4', 'a5'], 3: ['a6']}
```

Can i use groupby first and then do .to_dict?

Comment: there was a conversation about it there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695605/python-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need lists ad values of `dict` - use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) + [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby('key')['id'].apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{1: ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 2: ['a4', 'a5'], 3: ['a6']}
```

Or if need `list` with scalars add `if/else` to `apply`:

```
d = df.groupby('key')['id'].apply(lambda x: list(x) if len(x) > 1 else x.iat[0]).to_dict()
print (d)
{1: ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 2: ['a4', 'a5'], 3: 'a6'}
```

Comment: this is great if we have one column, however, what if we have to get values from multiple columns? I came across a similar situation. I tried using this, but no success. I think `map` would do it, but not sure! If you are willing, I posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623452/map-two-data-frames-to-create-a-dictionary-with-multiple-values-for-a-key-pand

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary comprehension around the `groupby` iterator

```
{n: v.tolist() for n, v in df.groupby('key').id}
```