# Covert a Pandas Dataframe to Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I been trying this for the past hour but with little to no success

I was wondering how can I make this dataframe to a dictionary

DF

```
 Country      Continent 
 1            Europe
 2            Europe
 3            Asia
 4            Australia
```

Desired

```
  {'1': 'Europe',
  '2': 'Europe',
  '3': 'Asia',
  '5': 'Australia'}
```

I tired like x10 different variations of code similar to this but it didn't work

```
 df.set_index('Country', inplace=True)
 df = df.to_dict('dict')
```

Comment: Duplicate of [python pandas dataframe to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695605/python-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary/18695700)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas dataframe to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695605/python-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 7):

You can select column `Continent` for `Series` and then use [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
>>> d = df.set_index('Country')['Continent'].to_dict()
>>> print(d)
{'Paris': 'Europe', 'Berlin': 'Europe', 'Macow': 'Asia', 'Melbourne': 'Australia'}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `dict` constructor with `zip`

```
dict(zip(df.Country, df.Continent))

{1: 'Europe', 2: 'Europe', 3: 'Asia', 4: 'Australia'}
```