# creating column with json format based on pandas columns

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have dataframe like below

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9
0 1 2
...
```

I need a new column D like below:

```
A B C D
1 2 3 {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3}
4 5 6 {'A':4,'B':5,'C':6}
7 8 9 {'A':7,'B':8,'C':9}
0 1 2 {'A':0,'B':1,'C':2}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you check the `pd.to_dict()` function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas dataframe to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695605/python-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `to_dict`

```
df['D'] = df.to_dict('records')
df
Out[11]: 
   A  B  C                         D
0  1  2  3  {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
1  4  5  6  {'A': 4, 'B': 5, 'C': 6}
2  7  8  9  {'A': 7, 'B': 8, 'C': 9}
3  0  1  2  {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}
```