# pandas dataframe to dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe from xlsx:

```
1  NaN  A     B     C
2  X   '1'   '11'  '111'
3  Y   '2'   '22'  '222'
4  Z   '3'   '33'  '333'
```

How to use pandas to convert to dict type like:

```
{X:{'A':'1','B':'11','C':'111'},
 Y:{'A':'2','B':'22','C':'222'},
 Z:{'A':'3','B':'33','C':'333'}}
```

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695605/python-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary

Comment: This question seems to be repetitive and has been answered in stack overflow. Please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple function for this:

```
df.to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.set_index('id').T.to_dict('records')
```

Its what I use...