# turn three columns into dictionary python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary, zip

```
Name = [list(['Amy', 'A', 'Angu']),
          list(['Jon', 'Johnson']),
          list(['Bob', 'Barker'])]

Other =  [list(['Amy', 'Any', 'Anguish']),
        list(['Jon', 'Jan']),
        list(['Baker', 'barker'])]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Other' : Other,  
                  'ID': ['E123','E456','E789'], 
                  'Other_ID': ['A123','A456','A789'],
                  'Name' : Name,

                 })

    ID              Name    Other               Other_ID
0   E123    [Amy, A, Angu]  [Amy, Any, Anguish] A123
1   E456    [Jon, Johnson]  [Jon, Jan]          A456
2   E789    [Bob, Barker]   [Baker, barker]     A789
```

I have the df as seen above. I want to make columns `ID`, `Name` and `Other` into a dictionary with they key being `ID`. I tried this according to [python pandas dataframe columns convert to dict key and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012505/python-pandas-dataframe-columns-convert-to-dict-key-and-value)

```
todict = dict(zip(df.ID, df.Name))
```

Which is close to what I want

```
{'E123': ['Amy', 'A', 'Angu'],
 'E456': ['Jon', 'Johnson'],
 'E789': ['Bob', 'Barker']}
```

But I would like to get this output that includes values from `Other` column

```
{'E123': ['Amy', 'A', 'Angu','Amy', 'Any','Anguish'],
 'E456': ['Jon', 'Johnson','Jon','Jan'],
'E789':  ['Bob', 'Barker','Baker','barker']
}
```

And If I put the third column `Other` it gives me errors

```
todict = dict(zip(df.ID, df.Name, df.Other))
```

How do I get the output I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just combine the `Name` and `Other` column before creating a dict of the `Name` column.

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'] + df['Other']

dict(zip(df.ID, df.Name))
```

Gives

```
{'E123': ['Amy', 'A', 'Angu', 'Amy', 'Any', 'Anguish'],
 'E456': ['Jon', 'Johnson', 'Jon', 'Jan'],
 'E789': ['Bob', 'Barker', 'Baker', 'barker']}
```