# Writing a specific dataframe column to a dictionary value without the associated index

Tags: python, pandas

Edit: I found my answer here
[python pandas dataframe columns convert to dict key and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012505/python-pandas-dataframe-columns-convert-to-dict-key-and-value)

Original post: 
I am attempting to write a specific dataframe column to a dictionary, yet I am also writing the index at the same time which I do not want. How do I do this the right way so I don't also include the index?

```
vi_dict = {}

vi_table_rvi = VI_table['RVI'].unique()

for d in vi_table_rvi:
    vi_dict[f'{d}'] = VI_table['AMT'].loc[(VI_table['RVI'] == d) & (VI_table['CD'] == 102)]
```

My dictionary output reads something like:

`key: index   value`

rather than

`key: value`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a pandas series in that case, in which you have the index. If you want to store the values only, use the [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html#pandas.Series.to_numpy)function. It will store a numpy array with the values of the series.

```
vi_dict[f'{d}'] = VI_table['AMT'].loc[(VI_table['RVI'] == d) & (VI_table['CD'] == 102)].to_numpy()
```

Comment: Thanks for the teaching. I didn't realize this was a series until investigating with type(). I did find the answer I was looking for in this post though, which involves the dict() and zip() methods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012505/python-pandas-dataframe-columns-convert-to-dict-key-and-value

Comment: Perfect. Then I suggest that you edit your question to mention that you found the answer.