# DataFrame : Convert Rows to dict python?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to convert dataframe rows to a dict.

df

```
       a            b
  
 0    paul         active
 1    marcus     inactive
 2    bruno        active
 3    scott      inactive
 4    anthony      active
```

To a dict from rows:

```
final_dict = {'paul':'active','marcus':'inactive','bruno':'active','scott':'inactive','anthony':'active'}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: value in the above reference is either in list or dict.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695605/python-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary, which was a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012505/python-pandas-dataframe-columns-convert-to-dict-key-and-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how:

```
d = {k:df['b'][df[df['a']==k].index.values[0]] for k in df['a']}
```

---

---

Breaking it down, here is how to find the index of a specific value in column:

```
val = 'value' # The value we want to find the index of
col = 'a' # The column the value is in
index = df[df[col]==val].index.values[0] # Here is how to find the index
```

Here is how you can find the value of a specific column given an index:

```
index = 3 The index of the column we want to find the value of
col = 'a' # The column which want to find a value in
value = df[col][index] # Here is how to find the value
```

So the dictionary will basically have the values of column `a`, and the values of column `b`, which we find those values that correspond to the values from `a` by using the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
import pandas as pd
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

you can refer [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: This is a beautiful duplicate that already has a nice answer, please delete your post and flag the question. If you keep your answer, you'll make next guys that come here stop their research and don't know the full detail, thanks